# Optimize/Reduce condition expression in if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, optimization

The goal is to optimize big condition expression by finding values dependencies between variables in order to **reduce the logical OR statements**.

Let's say we have the following condition:

```
if((A == 0 && B == 0) ||  (A == 0 && B == 1) || (A == 0 && B == 2) ...
```

a certain number of time...
Is there a way to reduce this kind of example by having automatically the following condition:

```
if(A == 0 && (B >= 0 && B <= 2))
```

The numbers involved in the first condition are only known just before the condition, it can't be typed manually. There can be also hundreds of logical OR operators involved in the condition. There can be gap between values (maybe use of % operator is needed) but **there is always a pattern**.

Any library or existing algorithm which can find the dependencies between the variables ?

Let's have another example:

```
if((A == 0 && B == 0) ||  (A == 0 && B == 2) || (A == 0 && B == 4)
```

can be *translated* to:

```
if((A == 0 && B%2 == 0)
```

One more:

```
if((A == 0 && B == 0 && C == 0) ||  (A == 0 && B == 2 && C == 0) || (A == 0 && B == 4 && C == 0) || (A == 0 && B == 0 && C == 1) ||  (A == 0 && B == 2 && C == 1) || (A == 0 && B == 4 && C == 1))
```

would be transformed into:

```
if(A==0 && B%2==0 && C>=0 && C<=1)
```

For the variables involved, I have all the values per terms.

I have something like `[[0,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,4,0],[0,0,1],[0,2,1],[0,4,1]]` (e.g. the last example)

Thanks for your time and answers !

Comment: well Discrete Math can help you (if you are a college student you probably already know, otherwise check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent). However this will help you only to simplify the conditions, but not with something like "%"

Comment: Can you have "mixed" or more complex pattern, `[[0, 2],[0, 4],[1,3],[1, 5]]` (`B%2=A`) or `(B+A) % 3 == 1`. From your example, it seems you can reasoning by individual variable, so testing some predefined pattern (constant, range, modulo with gcd, ...)

Comment: @Jarod42 There can be complex patterns but not mixed with 2 variables (```B%2=A``` can't happen), it's always linked to a constant

Comment: @Berto99 gonna take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

```
if((A == 0 && B == 0) ||  (A == 0 && B == 2) || (A == 0 && B == 4)
```

cannot be translated to

```
if((A == 0 && B%2 == 0)
```

cuz

```
B == 6
```

and etc

Comment: There is 2 choices: I have ```(A == 0 && B == 6)``` in the condition so it works or ```B``` will stop at the value 5 so there is no problem. It can continue until ```B == 6000``` or more but I can't predict it. This is for the example